# Javascript Parsing Large String

Tags: javascript, html, string, parsing

I have a fairly simple problem.

I have a large string and I want to grab a specific part of the string.

For example, in the body of text below I would like to get the phrase between the two bolded phrases.

At first I can simply use `.split('unique word')[1]` to get the phrase after the first bolded word.

However, I can't use `.split('nonunique word')[0]` directly on top of the string I got from the first split. (this returns an error for me saying that the string that I am trying to split is `undefined`).

In my specific situation the second phrase I'm trying to split on is repeated throughout the string multiple times, which is why I describe it as "nonunique word" in this example.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non 
>   fringilla eros, a pulvinar dolor. Nunc mauris nulla, consectetur egestas 
>   ipsum quis, **unique word** dui. Pellentesque nulla **nonunique word** 
>   quis pharetra sit amet, vulputate sit amet nisl. Aenean sit amet ipsum a elit 
>   vestibulum vulputate. Pellentesque interdum nisi sit amet.

Please let me know if there is a simple way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried chaining the splits, like so? `var text = myStr.split('unique word')[1].split('nonunique word')[0]`

Comment: Yes, as I've said in the original post that returns an error for me saying that I can't perform .split() on undefined

Comment: Oh, derp, sorry I missed that. So, that will happen if your unique word was not found. What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: The thing is though that it is found.. I simply take off the second split and the first split returns a string. But, as soon as I add the second .split() it says the first string is undefined.

Comment: The error you get is because splitting by `'unique word'` failed due to `'unique word'` not being found in the string. Are you sure it is always there? What do you do when it's not?

Comment: If the unique word is not found, the first split returns an array with 1 element, which is the entirety of the text. Then you are accessing [1], which does not exist, which is what resolves to undefined. Then you are trying to call `.split()` on undefined, hence the error. See my answer for how to resolve this issue.

Comment: How are you adding the second `split`? Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want it to return in the case that the unique word is not found in the text. If you want an empty string returned, you can just use a default, like so:

```js
var myStr = "my text has a unique word and also some nonunique word nonunique word nonunique word";
var myStr2 = "my text does not have any has a uniquewords";
           // if split()[1] is undefined (because unique word was not found), default to ""
var text = (myStr.split('unique word')[1] || "").split('nonunique word')[0];
           // if split()[1] is undefined (because unique word was not found), default to ""
var text2 = (myStr2.split('unique word')[1] || "").split('nonunique word')[0];
console.log(text);
console.log(text2);
```

Comment: @DariusMoseley You will still have the issue if your unique word is not found, which you should handle. My solution addresses that issue

Comment: Thanks for the help. Double split() works, was just syntax issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this actually doesn't involve `split` and would be better done with `substring`. You could something like this:

```
function getBetween(str, start, end){
    var startIndex = str.indexOf(start);
    var endIndex = str.indexOf(end);
    if(startIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0){
        return null;
    }
    return str.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
}
```

It basically finds the first occurrence of your first string, then finds the first occurrence of your second string that occurs after the first string, and returns everything in between.